# How to solve it simply to get difference equation have three branches meet to give y(n), 2 are coming from delayed output one coming from input

Tags: signal-processing, differential-equations, blockdiag

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3cJ8x.png)[rencve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQAP3.png)

In Figure.3 a block diagram of a certain system is shown with input () and output (). a. Find the difference equation that relates input to output. b. Find the system transfer function ().

Comment: Just write down the equations for each operation, you already have names for the operands. Then compose it all in one equation, leaving only input and output variables.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is off-topic, not programming related. Try math.SE, but really add some effort into the first solution steps. Most likely, doing the minimum to interpret the image will directly lead to the solution.